# JFactory not found

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I made a external file in Joomla `getuser.php` and place it at `administrator/getuser.php`

contain db queries

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->nameQuote('product_name'));
$query->from('#__virtuemart_products_en_gb');
$query->where($db->nameQuote('virtuemart_product_id').' = '.$db->quote($q));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $result['product_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
?>
```

and call it from `product_edit_information.php` using ajax located at administrator/components/com_virtuemart/views/product/tpl/product_edit_information.php

code is

```
<form>
<select name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="7745">YA Ali</option>
<option value="7746">Qasim</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

error is

> Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bc22\administrator\getuser.php on line 3

what is the reason of this error
how i add external files in joomla

i also go through this but cant understand...
http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_AJAX_to_your_component

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
```

when i put this at top of getuser.php it will give me error

**Restricted access**

when i `echo $q=$_GET["q"]; // output 7745 and 7746`

```
 <option value="7745">YA Ali</option>
 <option value="7746">Qasim</option>
```

but after jFactory not found error occurred

Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should add this code in top of your code:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/helper.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/toolbar.php';
```

the problem is that you don't include Joomla framework and using JFactory. If any function contains error, you should include Joomla path for that function.
`Restricted access` problem solved with `define('_JEXEC', 1);`